# Adding 3D vectors using SIMD intrinsics

Tags: c++, vectorization, simd, intrinsics, avx2

I've got two streams of 3D vectors which I'd like to add using x86 AVX2 intrinsics. I'm using the GNU compiler 11.1.0. Hopefully, the code illustrates what I want to do:

```
// Example program
#include <utility> // std::size_t

#include <immintrin.h>

struct v3
{
    float data[3] = {};
};

void add(const v3* a, const v3* b, v3* c, const std::size_t& n)
{
    // c <- a + b
    for (auto i = std::size_t{}; i < n; i += 2) // 2 vector3s at a time ~6 data
    {
        // masking
        // [95:0] of a[i] move into [255:128], [95:0] of a[i+1] move into [255:128] of *another* 256-bit register
        // ^same with b[i]
        static const auto p1_mask = _mm256_setr_epi32(-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        static const auto p2_mask = _mm256_setr_epi32(0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -1, 0, 0);
        
        const auto p1_leftop_packed = _mm256_maskload_ps(a[i].data, p1_mask);
        const auto p2_lefttop_packed = _mm256_maskload_ps(a[i].data, p2_mask);
        
        const auto p1_rightop_packed = _mm256_maskload_ps(b[i].data, p1_mask);
        const auto p2_rightop_packed = _mm256_maskload_ps(b[i].data, p2_mask);
        
        // addition is being done inefficiently with 2 AVX2 instructions!
        const auto result1_packed = _mm256_add_ps(p1_leftop_packed, p1_rightop_packed);
        const auto result2_packed = _mm256_add_ps(p2_leftop_packed, p2_rightop_packed);
        
        // store them back
        _mm256_maskstore_ps(c[i].data, p1_mask, result1_packed);
        _mm256_maskstore_ps(c[i].data, p2_mask, result2_packed);
    }
}



int main()
{
    // data
    const auto n = std::size_t{1000};
    v3 a[n] = {};
    v3 b[n] = {};
    v3 c[n] = {};
    
    // run
    add(a, b, c, n);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The above code works but the performance is quite terrible. To correct it, I think I need a version which looks approximately like the following:

```
    // c <- a + b
    for (auto i = std::size_t{}; i < n; i += 2) // 2 vector3s at a time ~6 data
    {
        // masking
        // [95:0] of a[i] move into [255:128], [95:0] of a[i+1] in [127:0]
        const auto leftop_packed = /*code required here*/;
        const auto rightop_packed = /*code required here*/;
        
        // addition is being done with only 1 AVX2 instruction
        const auto result_packed = _mm256_add_ps(leftop_packed, rightop_packed);
        
        // store them back
        // [95:0] of result_packed move into c[i], [223:128] of result_packed into c[i+1]
        /*code required here*/
    }
```

How do I achieve this? I will gladly provide any additional information when needed. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you can just load 8 floats at a time and then if you have anything left over at the end you can do a masked store (not sure about this part).

Comment: Use `char*`, `float*` or `__m256*` to work in 32-byte or 8-float chunks, ignoring vector boundaries since you're just doing pure vertical element-wise addition.  `float*` should be good for cleanup of the last up-to-7 floats.

Comment: Thank you, simple and elegant. I'll confirm once I've achieved the expected performance.

Comment: @LHLaurini Suggested solution works just fine. The trouble lies in the next step, which I hadn't highlighted in this question: I will need to do a dot product of one of the vectors, an operation which is not layout-agnostic because it operates on triplets of data. But that's a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two following comments say the same. They are good. Do as they say.

I think you can just load 8 floats at a time and then if you have anything left over at the end you can do a masked store (not sure about this part). – [LHLaurini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4184203/lhlaurini)

Use `char*`, `float*`, or `__m256*` to work in 32-byte or 8-float chunks, ignoring vector boundaries since you're just doing pure vertical addition.  `float*` should be good for cleanup of the last up-to-7 floats – [Peter Cordes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes)

Answer (score 0):

The [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page&_sm_au_=iVVvnk3Dq0rVsJHqL321jK0f1JH33) library supports vectorization. It also has a lot of the vector/matrix math algorithms already implemented, and quite efficiently too. If you can, I'd recommend looking into using it instead of rolling your own logic.

Comment: That [doesn't work so well here](https://godbolt.org/z/qEYWWbfrj), looks like the vectorization is trying very hard to put x components together in one SIMD vector, y components in another etc, all that of that permuting is completely unnecessary

Comment: I'm rather trying to learn how to use intrinsics than trying to get a task done.